# Bill of Materials

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to figure out how best to achieve this. I am working on a project using MS access and have the following "components" table;

```
+ -------------- + -------------- +
| component_ID   | description    |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
| APP0001        | Apple          |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
| BAN0001        | Banana         |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
| WAT0001        | Water          |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
| JUI0001        | Juice          |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
| BOT0001        | Bottle         |
+ -------------- + -------------- +
```

I then have a secondary table "BOMs" where I will assign child components to a parent component;

```
+ -------------- + -------------- + --- +
| parent         | child          | qty |
+ -------------- + -------------- + --- +
| JUI0001        | BAN0001        |  4  |
+ -------------- + -------------- + --- +
| JUI0001        | APP0001        |  2  |
+ -------------- + -------------- + --- +
| JUI0001        | WAT0001        |  5  |
+ -------------- + -------------- + --- +
| BOT0001        | JUI0001        |  2  |
+ -------------- + -------------- +---- +
```

My question is now how do I tie all of this together. Using SQL if I wanted to order x2 bottles, I would need x4 Juice and so on. This will allow me to see stock shortages and how much of things to order. But I dont quite understand how I could achieve a full list of all components I would need. Would I achieve this via a culmination of several union queries?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a simple group by

```
  Select parent, sum(qty) from
  Boms group by parent
```